# Unable to get FormFactory to fill array values on `submit`. Wrong form type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have created an [integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928694/200987) to debug an actual issue that seems to stem from upgrading from Symfony 3.3 to 3.4. The issue is that all my `array` fields on the entity (Doctrine ORM annotated as the type `json_array` on the field and stored as `json` in Postgres) should be filled from values in the `$requestEntity` that I submit, but they all turn out as `null`. Is there something off in the type definitions? I am really not sure how the entity class ties in with the "filling" of the entity vs the form type definition, so I will list the relevant bits from both.

**EDIT: Clarification on what this data is**

The `$requestEntity` here is not literal user input, but parsed JSON from an API endpoint. I am not sure whether using the Forms functionality is the right way to go about validating and working with non-form data, but that was the choice of whomever wrote this.

**Code where `scoreCols` is always `null` after `submit()`**

```
        $requestEntry = array(
            'id' => 'C4F1D2A3-762D-4548-B0E3-C0B3912FC02C',
            'score_cols' =>
                array(
                    0 => 'REPS',
                    1 => 'PAUSE',
                    2 => 'KG_WEIGHTS',
                )
        // other fields trimmed for brevity
        );

        $model = new ExerciseInfo();
        $formFactory = $container->get("form.factory");
        $form = $formFactory->create(ApiExerciseInfoType::class, $model);
        $form->submit($requestEntry);

        /**
         * @var $data ExerciseInfo
         */
        $entity = $form->getData();

        // $cols should be something like ["REPS", "PAUSE", "REPS"], but is always null!
        $cols = $entity->getScoreCols();
```

**Entity class: ExerciseInfo**

```
class ExerciseInfo
{
   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="score_cols", type="json_array", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $scoreCols; // will contain array  of types eg:  ["REPS", "KG_WEIGHTS", "PAUSE"]
...
```

**Form Type definition**

```
class ApiExerciseInfoType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('exercise_id', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'PETE\BackendBundle\Entity\Exercise',
                'property_path' => 'exercise',
            ])
            ->add('notes_sets', null, [])
            ->add('exercise_notes', null, [])
            ->add('score_cols', TextType::class, [
                'property_path' => 'scoreCols'
            ])
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyProj\BackendBundle\Entity\ExerciseInfo',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

**Tech details**

```
symfony/symfony v3.4.49
symfony/phpunit-bridge  v3.4.47
doctrine/annotations    1.13.2
doctrine/cache  1.12.1
doctrine/collections    1.6.8
doctrine/common 2.13.3
doctrine/data-fixtures  1.5.2
doctrine/dbal   2.13.7
doctrine/deprecations   v0.5.3
doctrine/doctrine-bundle    1.12.13
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle  1.4.0
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle   v2.4.1
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle v1.3.2
doctrine/event-manager  1.1.1
doctrine/inflector  1.4.4
doctrine/instantiator   1.4.0
doctrine/lexer  1.2.2
doctrine/migrations v1.8.1
doctrine/orm    2.7.5
doctrine/persistence    1.3.8
doctrine/reflection 1.2.2
```

Comment: Can you try with `CollectionType` instead of `TextType` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no big change. By adding `var_dump($cols)` I could see that its type changed from `NULL` to an empty array (`array(0) {}`).

Comment: @msg Hmm. Then what good does the `property_path` in the form type definition do? There is some kind of transformation not happening here.

Comment: @msg Trying to rename the snake case field to camelCase did nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you literally expecting the user to type something like ["REPS", "PAUSE", "REPS"] into the text type field?  Complete with punctuation and brackets etc?  Valid json?  If not then I would also expect there would a transformation class in the mix somewhere.

Comment: After some googling for "symfony array form" I found lots of references of this breaking in 3.4. Apparently stuffing array data in `TextType` was a misuse of that, so Nicolas Grekas added a PR that explicitly filtered that stuff out. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/29307

Comment: @Cerad This is an "ApiController" that just accepts JSON, not literal user input. I am not that well versed in Symfony, but it seems that the Forms functionality might be misused/misplaced here to do input validation of sorts. I did not write the original code (my background is from JVM, Node, Python) :D In any case, this was working with 3.3 and it seems from the PR mentioned in my previous comment, that this was changed in a patch release in 3.4.21. Any tips on how I should change this to work? Maybe using `EntityType` with `'multiple' => true` somehow? Not sure to make it work with arrays

Comment: Not really sure I can help.  Reading the pr makes it seem that other people have had similar issues.  I guess that your $requestEntry represents what is actually being posted?  Seems like a classic case for a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/data_transformers.html).  But if so then I don't really understand why the pr discussion did not recommend that.  Pretty sure that using EntityType is not going to work because the scoreCol is not an entity.  This is all speculation on my part.  Good luck.

Comment: @Cerad I found a workaround (posted as an answer) using a custom data type. Still feels like hack, but I can have a look at your data transformation tip once I have a working unit test :)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony made a breaking change in its 3.4.21 release by being stricter about what `TextType` would allow. As I updated to the latest available release, 3.4.49, I got stung. It is now [filtering arrays out of scalar types](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/29307).

In [a related issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29809), one Alexander Schranz posted [a workaround](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29809#issuecomment-451994583):

```
class UnstructuredType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'compound' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

That was what I needed: I just replaced the use of `TextType` with `UnstructuredType` and presto. As Cerad mentions in the comments, the general approach is probably wrong and one should probably go for a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/data_transformers.html) (I have not yet looked at that).