# Symfony 5.4 ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\EventManagement\Form\EventType::__construct() 0 passed 1 expected

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms

as soon as I call up the form builder into my unit test I get the following exception:
[image]

```
class EventFormBuilderTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testSuccessfullyCreatesForm(): void
    {
        $formBuilder = new EventFormBuilder($this->factory);

        $user = new User();
        $actualEvent = new Event();
        
        $form = $formBuilder->buildFormBasedOnUserRole($user, $actualEvent);
```

I injected a repository into my form to have default options:

```
class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var LegalServiceRepository */
    private $legalServiceRepository;

    public function __construct(LegalServiceRepository $legalServiceRepository)
    {
        $this->legalServiceRepository = $legalServiceRepository;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefined(['services']);
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('services', 'App\Entity\LegalService[]');
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Event::class,
            'services' => $this->legalServiceRepository->findAllOfTypeEvent(),
            'error_mapping' => [
                '.' => 'court',
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

Then I wrote a custom form builder that allows me to create a different form based on the user's role. The `GlobalAdminEventType` form extends `EventType`. I simply needed an extra field.
This works perfectly like expected and i get my options without any error.

```
class EventFormBuilder
{
    /** @var FormFactoryInterface */
    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct(
        FormFactoryInterface $formFactory
    ) {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function buildFormBasedOnUserRole(User $user, Event $event): FormInterface
    {
        if (\in_array(RolesEnum::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, $user->getRoles(), true)) {
            $form = $this->buildForm(GlobalAdminEventType::class, $event);
        } else {
            $event->setCourt($user->getCourt());
            $form = $this->buildForm(EventType::class, $event);
        }
        return $form;
    }

    public function buildForm(string $type, Event $event): FormInterface
    {
        return $this->formFactory->create($type, $event);
    }
}
```

Comment: are your services set to be autowired (in `config/services.yaml`)?

Comment: It cannot be the problem.. Is everything settled and working as expected... The problem come up just when i run the test

Comment: Form testing does not pass dependencies automatically to your types. You can read about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html#testing-types-registered-as-services). As this looks like a functional test, you'll have to grab the service from the container instead of mocking it as the documentation suggests.

Comment: @msg thank you, it was helpfull.. But i don't understand what do you mean by: you'll have to grab the service from the container instead of mocking it

Comment: A service mock is a fake service that adheres to the interface of the original one but does not provide any functionality. You can use them to [check that the expected functions](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#) are called with the expected arguments and so forth. As I understand it, you want to actually call the original service (`LegalServiceRepository`) and get real data out of it, so you need a working instance of the repository (and its dependencies). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70927798) is basically the same as your, see if it helps.